# Lambda Calculus - Call-by-name AND call-by-value reduction

Tags: turing-machines, lambda-calculus

I have been tasked with reducing the following lambda expression:

> (λpq.pqp)(λab.a)(λab.b)

using call-by-name and call-by-value reduction strategies.

**Call-by-name**

strategy: Left-most, outermost redex first but no reduction under lambda.

Step 1) alpha-equivalence

> (λpq.pqp)(λab.a)(λcd.d)

Step 2) Reduction - using the redex (λpq.pqp)(λab.a)

> (λq.(λab.a)q(λab.a)(λcd.d)

Step 3) - substitute (λcd.d) for q

> (λab.a)(λcd.d)(λab.a)

Step 4) - substitute (λcd.d) for a

> (λb.(λcd.d))(λab.a)

Step 5) - substitute (λab.a) for b

> (λcd.d) -> (λab.b)

*Which gives the same result if you were to use normal order instead.*

**Call-by-value**

strategy: Right-most, innermost redex first but no reduction under lambda

Step 1) alpha-equivalence

> (λpq.pqp)(λab.a)(λcd.d)

Step 2) substitute (λab.a) for c

> (λpq.pqp)(λd.d)

Step 3) substitute (λpq.pqp) for d

> (λpq.pqp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstood call-by-value and are doing it backwards, i.e., you are substituting functions into arguments, instead of the other way around. Call-by-value and call-by-name both use the same rules of reduction, but in different places and in a different order.

In your case the call-by-value and call-by-name do not differ, because the arguments are already reduced.

Here is an example, where the difference matters. Reduce

```
(λpq.pqp)((λab.a)(λcd.d))
```

Note that this is different from your examples bacause of the extra parantheses that I put in.

Call-by-name:

```
(λpq.pqp)((λab.a)(λcd.d)) ➝
λq.((λab.a)(λcd.d))q((λab.a)(λcd.d)) ➝
λq.((λab.a)(λcd.d))q((λab.a)(λcd.d)) ➝
λq.(λb.(λcd.d))q((λab.a)(λcd.d)) ➝
λq.(λcd.d)((λab.a)(λcd.d)) ➝
λq.(λd.d)
```

Call-by-value:

```
(λpq.pqp)((λab.a)(λcd.d)) ➝
(λpq.pqp)(λb.(λcd.d)) ➝
(λpq.pqp)(λb.(λcd.d)) ➝
λq.(λbcd.d)q(λbcd.d) ➝
λq.(λcd.d)(λbcd.d) ➝
λq.(λd.d)
```

The difference is that in call-by-value you normalize the argument before you substitute it for the bound variable.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much I think I have better understanding. I do have another question as I'm not sure if I understand what they mean by _no reduction under lambda_ so let's say we reduced an expression using  **call-by-value** and it reduced to the following: </br> <pre><code> (λb.(λc.v)b)➝ </pre></code> </br> would that be the final result?

Comment: No reduction under $\lambda$ means that we never reduce inside a $\lambda$-abstraction. For example $\lambda x . ((\lambda y . y) x)$ is considered reduced because the only reduction that we can make is inside a $\lambda$-abstraction.